# Undefined index in variable initialising

Tags: indexing, undefined

```
$result2 = mysql_query($query, $con);
            while($data2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
            {
                $x = $data2["x"];
                $y = $data2["y"];
                echo "$x";
                echo "$y";
                if($x<0 && $y<0)
                {
                    echo "village: $data[village]  ";
                    echo "player: $data[player]  ";
                    echo "position: ($data[x]|$data[y])<br>";
                }
                else if($x>0 && $y>0)
                {
                    echo "village: $data[village]  ";
                    echo "player: $data[player]  ";
                    echo "position: ($data[x]|$data[y])<br>";
                }
                else if($x>0 && $y<0)
                {
                    echo "village: $data[village]  ";
                    echo "player: $data[player]  ";
                    echo "position: ($data[x]|$data[y])<br>";
                }
            }
```

I am getting the error

```
Notice: Undefined index: y in C:\xampp\htdocs\debal\nw_check_exec.php on line 48

Notice: Undefined index: x in C:\xampp\htdocs\debal\nw_check_exec.php on line 47
```

line 47 and line 48 are:-

```
$x = $data2["x"];
$y = $data2["y"];
```

I think i have done all things properly, and i am unable to figure out the cause of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properbly the `$data2` has really no index `x` so you need to check that and use instat a default value.

You can use for that a small inline if statment:

```
$x = isset($data2["x"]) ? $data2["x"] : 0;
$y = isset($data2["y"]) ? $data2["y"] : 0;
```

By the way do you have really defined so much constants? E.g. here:

```
$data[village]
```

This means that there must be a constant `village` maybe with some value "village"?

Maybe you should exchange that with a:

```
$data["village"]
```

Comment: the table in question here has the columns "x" "y" "village" "player"

Comment: Try a var_dump($data2) to check what is retuned by the database. Are there all columns like expected?

Comment: Thanks for the var_dump idea, that helped me figure out the error i had made.. (a typo)...